# Core Bluetooth Swift get devices name

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm studying Core Bluetooth framework and I did a test project about it for learning:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
    {
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
    {
        let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
            .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
            as? NSString

        let isMyIphone = device?.contains("iPhone")

    }
}
```

For starting I would like to see Bluetooth name around me, for this reason I have 2 iPhone.
One I use for execute this 'app' for scanning and I would like to see the name of the other iPhone (in Bluetooth setting is name is 'iPhone'), but when I start scanning the method 'didDiscover' is called but the device constant is nil. 
Why? What I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

is better if you use 
peripheral.name 
instead
let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
            .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
            as? NSString

Comment: Thanks for responding! Your response isn't technically an _answer_, you merely suggest that it would be 'better' if the user did something differently. Better _how_, exactly? A few things that would be helpful: 1) take advantage of SO's support for formatting and say, e.g., "use `peripheral.name` instead of `let device = ((advertisementData as NSDictionary) .object(...)`, and 2) If you've seen your suggested change solve problems like the one the original poster is having, _say so_ explicitly, e.g., "I have seen _exactly_ the behavior you're describing, and switching to (...) fixed it."